# How to execute multiple commands on Terminal, from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, terminal, zip

Currently trying to compress with encryption a couple of files, on Ubuntu.

I need them to be **.zip**.

What I would normally do, is write in terminal:

`zip -e secretDir.zip secretFile.txt`

This will normally ask for a password, like:

```
Enter password: secret
Verify password: secret
```

with the exception that the password is not actually displayed. This works perfectly well.

However I am trying to do this from my Python script (3.7).

I have `subprocess.call(['zip', '-e', fileName + '.zip', fileName + '.txt'])`

This works fine, however how am I now supposed to tell zip what the password is?

Open source libraries that might do encryption when compressing files are welcome. I have already heard about chilkat and CkPython.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the password directly to the `zip` command using the `-p` parameter.

```
subprocess.call(['zip', '-P', 'MyPassW0rd123', fileName + '.zip', fileName + '.txt'])
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It still asks for password and to verify it, and after I've input both, it creates a `MyPassW0rd123.zip`, and it issues a warning "zip warning: name not matched: fileName.zip"

Comment: Sorry, you need to remove the `-e` flag.  Fixed now.  (Also, make sure it is a capital `-P`.)

Comment: It works now. The lowercase -p was the problem. Thanks!